# Demo account with Firebase google sign for App Store review

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-signin

Trying to submit my app to Apple App Store.  It uses only Google Sign in for authentication.  How do I provide a test account they can use.  I tried supplying a spare gmail account I use for testing on my side, but they were block as suspicious activity

Comment: Doesn't Apple require that you always offer Apple sign-in now?

Comment: Thats true, and have set up Apple sign-in, but still need to provide a demo account for apple sign in.  Is there a way to create an apple id that will work?